# Doing brew update fatal: unable to access '.git/config': Permission denied mac os catalina

Tags: macos, homebrew, updates, macos-catalina, homebrew-cask

[Screenshot]
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDl3w.png)fatal: unable to access '.git/config': Permission denied
warning: unable to access '.git/config': Permission denied
fatal: unable to access '.git/config': Permission denied
warning: unable to access '.git/config': Permission denied
fatal: unable to access '.git/config': Permission denied

I'm doing command brew update
I have the ZSH shell installed as well and I'm using Iterm also the same error on original terminal

Comment: Running with sudo? Show the _actual_ commands and _actual_ errors, from the console.

Comment: Mention what you have done, to get this result, and add screenshots and possibly  environment details for more clarity on your question.

Comment: running homebrew as root is not allowed

Comment: @tHeSiD how do I get that environment details?

Comment: Which command did you execute, where did you execute it, was it with elevated permissions? What is the directory structure? What are you trying to update etc

Comment: @tHeSiD i was just checking to see if there was any new update on homebrew but i checked the version on github and the one in my system its the latest and everything working fine.  i ran brew update and  threw that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After your fresh `homebrew` installation, you should always run `sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*` to do the one-time permission setup.

This is because `homebrew` is trying to setup the [brew repo](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew) for brew in your local.

Comment: thanks i got it fix but this was the issues anyways my solution at the time was to completely delete homebrew and reinstall